# Create spark Dataframe based on another dataframe with json column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a Spark Dataframe (json_df) and I need to create another Dataframe based on the json nested:

This is my current Dataframe:

[image]

I know I could do that manually like: `final_df = json_df.select( col("Body.EquipmentId"),..... )` but I want to do that in a generic way.

note: for this specific DF, the json records has the same structure.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: would `json_df.select('Body.*')` work?

Comment: You right @werner... a solution for this could be:
     `Final_df = json_df.select(col("body.*"))`

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically, you can do it like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)

df = sc.parallelize([({"A":1, "B":2},), ({"A":3,"B":4},), ({"A":5,"B":6},)]).toDF(['Body'])
keys_df = df.select(F.explode(F.map_keys(F.col('Body')))).distinct()
keys = list(map(lambda row: row[0], keys_df.collect()))
key_cols = list(map(lambda f: F.col("Body").getItem(f).alias(str(f)), keys))
final_cols = df.select(key_cols)
final_cols.show()
```

Which produces

```
+---+---+
|  B|  A|
+---+---+
|  2|  1|
|  4|  3|
|  6|  5|
+---+---+
```

If you have the entire list of keys already, you can skip the part where it gets the keys and just set the keys manually:

```
keys = ['A', 'B']
```

Source: https://mungingdata.com/pyspark/dict-map-to-multiple-columns/